# jquery selector, capture text without tag around it

Tags: jquery, text, selector, capture

What i'm trying to accomplish here is to capture the Brand name, which in this case is Tommy Hilfiger. 
What i've got so far is `jQuery("[class*='product']")`

However, this captures the word shoes as well. Anyway that i can just capture Tommy hilfiger? as i am not the creator of the website i cannot just put a < p > tag around the brand-name. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<div class="fc-list-item fc-l-product">

<a href="/product/index/product_id/1451556">Shoes</a>
            <br>
            Tommy Hilfiger        
            <div class="articul">FW56819057 719 LIGHT GOLD</div>


</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text nodes using:

```
$('.fc-l-product').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3; //get text nodes
});
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not how our system works. 
if you navigate to http://www.butik.ru/checkout/onepage and put something in the basket. Open console in Chrome and use jQuery("[class*='product']") you will see what i mean

Comment: Yes it does, u have to navigate back to the basket-page. 
then open the console and type that in :)

Comment: Our system can only use jQuery selectors, hence why i need to know if there is something that can be accomplished with jquery

Comment: yes, but it's not jquery selectors. anyhow, i'm not going to argue with you here. I was just curious if it was accomplish-able.
Eg, `jQuery("[class*='product']:not(a)")` doesn't solve the issue either.
I solely want the text within the div, not the a tag n'or the div below. (which i am getting)

Comment: It is russian right? How can i navigate to basket page??

Comment: I'm not russian, just translate the page (right-click translate). Please note that you get <code> everywhere in your code if you translate. so translate it back once you're on the right page :)

Comment: My guess is that we probably need to ask the client to put a <p / span> tag around the brand-name.